# Only add thousand separator before decimal comma

Tags: jquery, regex, currency

I have found a regex on stackoverflow to add a ',' or '.' after every third number depending on your language.

```
(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))
```

The problem is that it also happens when we reach the decimal point like with for example:

```
5487445.46878
```

The result of that with the following code (and regex) is:

```
return number.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
```

Which results in:

```
5,487,445.46,878
```

I'm using this regex when I'm converting a number depending on your language. In Dutch for example a comma is used as a seperator, so there I do the following:

```
return number.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1.")
```

Which results in

```
5.487.445,46.878
```

These of course need to become:

```
5,487,445.46878
```

and

```
5.487.445,4687
```

*Does anybody know where I need to update the regex to ignore the decimal point?*

Comment: Since you flagged this with jQuery I would suggest to use http://plugins.jquery.com/df-number-format/

Comment: 1-up for the interesting suggestion I hadn't found yet. I think I can use that and merge it with what I have since your suggestion doesn't have support for different languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use your `RegEx` but split your number first if its has a comma or point in it.

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Techsolo/tPxr7/)

```
 var input = '5487445.46878';
 var parts = input.split('.');
 var part1 = parts[0].replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
 var part2 = parts[1];

 alert(part1 + '.' + part2);
```

Comment: I've implemented this in my jquery enxtion method and it works perfectly. Thank you for the easy and simple solution. I did however shrink it a wee bit. http://jsfiddle.net/4kb9R/71/

Comment: np. for better understanding i did not shrink it ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:-

```
    function thousandsSeparator(input) {
    var output = input
    if (parseFloat(input)) {
        input = new String(input);
        var parts = input.split("."); 
        parts[0] = parts[0].split("").reverse().join("").replace(/(\d{3})(?!$)/g, "$1,").split("").reverse().join("");
        output = parts.join(".");
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. Also does strange things when you add larger numbers.

Comment: @reaper_unique:- Updated my answer. Please check. It will surely work!! :)

Comment: Thanks, will check it out asap. But ehm, didn't you updated it with pieces of the answer of Martin?

Comment: @reaper_unique:- Do let me know if this works or not works for you!! ;)

Comment: I'll up you for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

With ECMAScript 2018+ compliant `RegExp`, you can use

```
text = text.replace(/(?<!\.\d*)(\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yw4Lgh/1). *Details*:

- `(?<!\.\d*)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a `.` and then zero or more digits immediately to the left of the current location
- `(\d)` - any one digit captured into Group 1
- `(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))` - a positive lookahead that requires one or more sequences of three digits not immediately followed with another digit immediately to the right of the current location.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const re = /(?<!\.\d*)(\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g;
[
    {str: "123456789.123456789", expect: "123,456,789.123456789"},
    {str: "123456789", expect: "123,456,789"},
    {str: "12345678.123456789", expect: "12,345,678.123456789"},
    {str: "12345678",      expect: "12,345,678"},
    {str: "1234567.123456789",      expect: "1,234,567.123456789"},
    {str: "1234567",      expect: "1,234,567"}
].forEach(test);

function test(entry) {
    const result = entry.str.replace(re, "$1,");
    console.log(`Testing ${entry.str}, got ${result}, ${(result == entry.expect ? "OK" : "ERROR")}`);
}
```