# Regexp to add commas in thousands, millions, etc (but avoiding adding them after the decimal point) Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, floating-point, decimal

The problem is quite simple, we need to put commas in their correct places to help users to format a number in the right way.

For example if the user enters:

> 123123123.534343

the result should be:

> 123,123,123.534343

and what we have now is this: (fails when there is not '.')

> str.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d).)/g, ',');

and this: (fails because it adds commas in the decimal part, after the '.')

> str.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');

Any ideas?

Comment: Split the string with dot, apply the regex to the whole part and join back.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513518/only-add-thousand-separator-before-decimal-comma?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to use [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) to format numbers as it is language dependent

```js
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US').format(123123123.534343));
```

Comment: Nice one! didn't know about this, I'll give it a try, thanks. What about compatibility? is this cross-nav @Hyyan?

Comment: You can also pass an options object with ```minimumFractionDigits``` so it won't truncate the number after the point

Comment: @Hugo , according to [canIuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=NumberFormat) it is well supported, but if you need a polyfill to support older browsers then there is [andyearnshaw/Intl.js](https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js/)

Answer (score 0):

Example of regex for numbers with 4 digits before the decimal:

```
echo 1234.556 | sed 's/\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\)\(\.[0-9]*\)/\1,\2\3\4\5/'
```

You need to update it accordingly for a different number of digits (but be aware that there is a limit of 9 for the matched patterns, for sed at least, so this will work for up to 8 digits before the decimal dot).