# Every thousand digit

Tags: regex

### This is a quiz exercise

Use substitution to put commas in all numbers to separate the thousands. ie: 12345678 → 12,345,678. The number could be in a sentence, and there may be more than one number in the sentence.

I tried the code

```
/(\d{3})(\d{3})/g
```

Results returns

> Test 6/19: 100013541615681651 should become 100,013,541,615,681,651. Did you forget the global flag?

Tried it

```
/\d(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g
```

Results returns

> Test 14/19: Your regex is incorrectly replacing the number in the following string: Your ticket number is A87654

Regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/QAHt6E/8)

Matched String

```
12345678901234567890

12345678

1234567
```

Unmatched String

```
A87654
```

Expected results

```
123,456789,012345,67890

123,45678

123,4567

A87654
```

[image]

### Reference

[Matching Whole Lines of Text](https://www.regular-expressions.info/completelines.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a regex that won't match numbers which are connected to some letters as well:

```
(?=\b\d|\G)\d+?(?=(?:\d{3})+\b)
```

`(?=\b\d|\G)` is a lookahead for either a word break and a digit, or the end of the previous match . `\d+?` looks for a minimal number of digits and then `(?=(?:\d{3})+\b)` asserts that it is followed at least one group of 3 digits and then another word break. The word breaks at the beginning and end of the regex mean that it cannot match numbers that are part of an alphanumeric string.

This should be replaced with `$0,` to insert commas into the numbers.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/QAHt6E/9)

Answer (score 4):

Lookahead for a repeated group of 3 digits, followed eventually by negative lookahead for a digit:

```
\d(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))
```

and replace with

```
$0,
```

https://regex101.com/r/QAHt6E/5

Comment: It has the same answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513518/only-add-thousand-separator-before-decimal-comma

Comment: @Joseph That's negative lookahead for a digit - it ensures that what immediately follows the repeated group of 3 (or 6, or 9...) digits is not another digit.

Comment: Test 14/19: Your regex is incorrectly replacing the number in the following string: Your ticket number is A87654.

Comment: @Joseph The result for that string is `A87,654` - the numeric part of the string is properly separated out by thousands. If you didn't want that to match, can you explain why?

Comment: This is a Regex101 quiz. It provides an initial condition until you input the more matched strings, additional conditions will show on the screen. https://imgur.com/6EKg1ay.png

Comment: @LyuJH Ok, but can you answer the question I asked? What is the expected result in that case, and why? Once that's known, the code can be altered to account for it.

Comment: I am not sure how many conditions are expected. In this case, you will see Test 14/19 which means you have matched 14 strings but remain 5 strings unknown. I thought you are close to the final answer. I will try to solve the problem.

Comment: @LyuJH Can you please answer the question I asked, so I can fix the code? What output were you expecting instead of `A87,654`, and why?

Comment: I will try to get rid of non-digit strings. It possibly worked.